# Showing and hiding content

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I miraculously produced my own webpage using Dreamweaver CS6 and a CSS Bootstrap Template that I found.  I am a ROOKIE...and am shocked I've gotten this far. Site for ref: http://www.pauldemarcostudios.com

My question:
I want to Show and Hide content particularly for long paragraphs. Maybe with a "Read More" link or a "Read More" button.  My "Services" page template has "Read More" buttons with the following code:

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary pull-right" href="#">Read More</a>
```

I understand that if I replace the "#" after href, then I can denote a link for the button to connect to (a picture, website, another page, etc.)

But I want more text to show when the Read More button is pressed. I don't want to link to a different page or file.

CSS Bootstrap page gives the following:

Showing and hiding content
Force an element to be shown or hidden (including for screen readers) with the use of .show and .hidden classes. These classes use !important to avoid specificity conflicts, just like the quick floats. They are only available for block level toggling. They can also be used as mixins.

.hide is available, but it does not always affect screen readers and is deprecated as of v3.0.1. Use .hidden or .sr-only instead.

Furthermore, .invisible can be used to toggle only the visibility of an element, meaning its display is not modified and the element can still affect the flow of the document.

HTML:

```
<div class="show">...</div>
<div class="hidden">...</div>
```

// Classes

```
.show {
  display: block !important;
}
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

// Usage as mixins

```
.element {
  .show();
}
.another-element {
  .hidden();
}
```

I basically understand how to use the HTML code.  But where does the other code,

```
.element {
  .show();
}
.another-element {
  .hidden();
}
```

for example go?  When I put it in the head it shows as text on my page.

Alternately, If I highlight text in a Paragraph tag and assign it a "hidden text" class via the DW interface....the text hides, but I have no way of referencing it to get it to show.  I tried to put the "Class Title"....for example "Hidden Text", which is the tag that wraps the text that I highlighted, in place of the "#" after href but that didn't work.

Hope this makes sense.  Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Your example 'other code' makes no sense at all. You seem to have mixed JavaScript with CSS.

Comment: Ok...this is the rookie in me.  Thank you for your attention. On my post, "CSS Bootstrap page..." to the "code" that you comment about is copied and pasted from the CSS Bootstrap page. This is precisely where I'm confused.  What do I do with that information? Where do I put it? Do I need to make a CSS or JavaScript file to put that in? or does it go in the Head?  Again, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

**HTML**

```
<button class="button" onclick="$('#more').toggle();">Read More</button>
<div id="more">I understand that if I replace the "#" after href, then I can denote a link for the button to connect to (a picture, website, another page, etc.)

But I want more text to show when the Read More button is pressed. I don't want to link to a different page or file.

CSS Bootstrap page gives the following:

Showing and hiding content Force an element to be shown or hidden (including for screen readers) with the use of .show and .hidden classes. These classes use !important to avoid specificity conflicts, just like the quick floats. They are only available for block level toggling. They can also be used as mixins.

.hide is available, but it does not always affect screen readers and is deprecated as of v3.0.1. Use .hidden or .sr-only instead.

Furthermore, .invisible can be used to toggle only the visibility of an element, meaning its display is not modified and the element can still affect the flow of the document.</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    padding:30px;
}
#more {
    height:auto;
    padding:5px;
}
```

[See Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3jcegzsf/)

Comment: Thank you Fabio.  This makes great sense.  But where do I put the "CSS" code that you provided above? Where does it go? Do I past in the Head?

Comment: no, just replace your current button with the first line and then add a div with ID (it has to be different for each div), so for div id "more", your button hast to target #more and so on. btw, nice work on the site and amazing portfolio

Comment: Sweet.  Many "Thank Yous" Fabio!!!!  I will give it a shot and let you know how it turns out.  Also, thank you for the kind words...like I said, can't believe I've gotten this far.  All the best...

Comment: It totally works.....the only issue I'm having is that the "more" text shows by default when the page loads.  The button does work, and hides the text when pressed.  The page is active now with the change so you can see what I mean.

Comment: ah, yes. Add a `class=hidden` to that div and it will work. If it doesn't, just add `.hidden{display:none}` . See updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/3jcegzsf/2/

Comment: You da Man, Fabio.  Done.  And it works great.  You just made my day....and my web developing skills that much more the better.  Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some simple jquery and target the specific elements you would like to show with an event handler like so:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('.hidden').css( "display", "block !important")
})
```

This will change the css to show those hidden elements.